# Integrating the Drag&Drop in eclipse

Tags: android, android-intent, drag-and-drop

Me and my team have encountered the problem upper mentioned. We are trying to create the start menu for a puzzle game, a menu in which we should be able to drag the playing options onto the logo in the middle, which is `"shuffleThis"`. Do you have any good advice on how to solve this?

We are also trying to integrate more bits of code and it will only get more difficult if we don't solve this now.

```
package com.agile.puzzle;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button butonRandomPlay;
    Button butonPlayFriends;
    Button butonLeaderBoard;
    Button butonAchievements;
    ImageView shuffleThis;
    View fereastra;

    public final static int razaButon = 50; 
    public final static int razaCentru = 75;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        butonRandomPlay= (Button) findViewById(R.id.randomPlay);
        butonPlayFriends= (Button) findViewById(R.id.playFriends);
        butonLeaderBoard= (Button) findViewById(R.id.leaderboard);
        butonAchievements=(Button) findViewById(R.id.achievements);
        shuffleThis = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.shuffleThis);
        fereastra = findViewById(R.id.fereastra);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b= getIntent().getExtras();
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //iau coord x pentru fiecare buton
        float b2x = butonRandomPlay.getX();
        float b1x = butonPlayFriends.getX();
        float b3x = butonLeaderBoard.getX();
        float b4x = butonAchievements.getX();

        //iau coord y pentru fiecare buton
        float b1y = butonPlayFriends.getY();
        float b2y = butonRandomPlay.getY();
        float b3y = butonLeaderBoard.getY();
        float b4y = butonAchievements.getY();

        //coord centru
        float cx = shuffleThis.getX();
        float cy = shuffleThis.getY();

        //coord eventului
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            //pentru cazul butonului 1
            //verific ca actiunea sa se intample in jurul butonului
            if (((b1x-razaButon)<=x)&&((b1x+razaButon)>=x)){
                if (((b1y-razaButon)<=y)&&((b1y+razaButon)>=y)){
                    //il plimb dupa deget
                    butonPlayFriends.setX(x);
                    butonPlayFriends.setY(y);
                    //System.out.println(x+","+y);

                    //verific daca ma apropii de centru in raza mica
                    //daca da, sare in centru
                        if (((cx-razaCentru)<=x)&&((cx+razaCentru)>=x)){
                            if (((cy-razaCentru)<=y)&&((cy+razaCentru)>=y)){
                                System.out.println("am ajuns 1!");
                                butonPlayFriends.setX(cx);
                                butonPlayFriends.setY(cy);
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }

        //pentru cazul butonului 2
            if (((b2x-razaButon)<=x)&&((b2x+razaButon)>=x)){
                if (((b2y-razaButon)<=y)&&((b2y+razaButon)>=y)){

                    butonRandomPlay.setX(x);
                    butonRandomPlay.setY(y);
                    //System.out.println(x+","+y);
                    if (((cx-razaCentru)<=x)&&((cx+razaCentru)>=x)){
                        if (((cy-razaCentru)<=y)&&((cy+razaCentru)>=y)){
                            //System.out.println("am ajuns 2!");
                            butonRandomPlay.setX(cx);
                            butonRandomPlay.setY(cy);
                        }
                    }   
                }
            }

        //pentru cazul butonului 3
            if (((b3x-razaButon)<=x)&&((b3x+razaButon)>=x)){
                if (((b3y-razaButon)<=y)&&((b3y+razaButon)>=y)){    
                    butonLeaderBoard.setX(x);
                    butonLeaderBoard.setY(y);
                    //System.out.println(x+","+y);
                    if (((cx-razaCentru)<=x)&&((cx+razaCentru)>=x)){
                        if (((cy-razaCentru)<=y)&&((cy+razaCentru)>=y)){
                            //System.out.println("am ajuns 3!");
                            butonLeaderBoard.setX(cx);
                            butonLeaderBoard.setY(cy);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        //pentru cazul butonului 4
            if (((b4x-razaButon)<=x)&&((b4x+razaButon)>=x)) {
                if (((b4y-razaButon)<=y)&&((b4y+razaButon)>=y)){
                    butonAchievements.setX(x);
                    butonAchievements.setY(y);
                    //System.out.println(x+","+y);
                    if (((cx-razaCentru)<=x)&&((cx+razaCentru)>=x)){
                        if (((cy-razaCentru)<=y)&&((cy+razaCentru)>=y)){
                            //System.out.println("am ajuns 4!");
                            butonAchievements.setX(cx);
                            butonAchievements.setY(cy);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        return false;
        }

    public void randomPlay(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RandomPlay.class);
        startActivity(i);       
    }

    public void playFriends (View v){   
        Intent i2 = new Intent(this, PlayFriends.class);
        startActivity(i2);  
    }

    public void leaderB (View v){   
        Intent i3 = new Intent(this, LeaderBoard.class);
        startActivity(i3);
    }

    public void achievements (View v){  
        Intent i4 = new Intent(this, Achievements.class);
        startActivity(i4);
    }



}
```